# Best pratice for unset local variable used in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, unset

I have the following code:

```
$strings = ...
$chars = array();

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    $firstChar = mb_substr($s, 0, 1, 'utf-8');

    if (!in_array($firstChar , $chars)) {
        array_push($chars, $firstChar);
    }
    // unset($firstChar); // HERE?
}

// unset($firstChar); // HERE?
```

Where should I put the `unset` of the `firstChar` variable? Inside the foreach? Outside? Is there a best practice to do this?

In languages like Java o C# the `firstChar` should die at the end of each iteration but in PHP there isn't a separate scope for this kind of variable (please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still a newbie with php)

I'd like the first `unset` but I'd like to hear your thoughts :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Whats your aim here, if its possible variable collision, either is fine, if its performance (and if your loop is actually that big its a real concern), you should look at ditching `in_array` and instead use the chars as the array index

Comment: If your code block is a part of function, then I don't see any reason to unset your variable at all. Garbage collector will do the job for you.

Comment: What is your purpose here? If your purpose is performance, then you should check your perfrormance at first. If there no performance problem, so you do not need to unset your variable. Your variable will be unseted by the garbage collector.

In my opinion you do not need to unset the variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it at the end, there's no point in unsetting it at the end of each iteration only to reassign it at the start of the iteration.

But generally if you're not going to use firstChar after the loop why unset it at all?

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no effect happening in your logic if you use unset in inside foreach loop or after the foreach loop because you are initialising this  $firstChar variable in each iteration.

But use unset after the foreach loop because if you are using unset in for loop it take some millisecond time to unset that variable.